# Is it possible to SSH a remote server using 2 different private keys for same user?

Tags: linux, ssh, unix, ssh-keys

```
     ___                                     ___  
    |   | (connecting using "hxsr")         |   |
    | A | -----------------------------> P1 | B |
    |___| -----------------------------> P2 |___|

P1 = Private key 1 from user "hxusr" from machine A
P2 = Private key 2 from user "hxusr" from machine A
```

As you can see I have only "hxusr" user in machine A and machine B, but I want to have to access machine B using 2 different private keys from machine A.

Is this possible?

Comment: I rewrote this with some English fixes based on my understanding of the question. If I was wrong in what you are after, please edit it again with a more complete explanation of what you want to accomplish.

Comment: as an aside, using different key pairs for different hosts is generally recommended (albeit less convenient) as one compromised private key does not equate to many/all compromised remote hosts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can certainly use your choice of more than one key, but I don't think SSH allows for requiring more than one key in a single connection. On the receiving side (your machine B) you specify a list of acceptable keys, and any of them that get provided will do the job.

Besides the config file [Ignacio mentions](https://serverfault.com/questions/270985/is-it-possible-to-ssh-a-remote-server-using-2-different-private-keys-for-same-use/270987#270987), the `ssh` command has a `-i` option that you can use to specify the key file of your choice when authenticating on a case by case basis when you run it.

Comment: Ok but how is the configuration at server side? I mean...will I put the 2 keys from A in in B's authorized_keys?

Comment: Yes, you put both of the public keys on separate lines of authorized_keys.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Use multiple `Host` stanzas in `~/.ssh/config`, each with a different key. See the `ssh_config(5)` man page for details.